# Android спрятать BottomNavigation при прокрутке

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_selected"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_selected"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Идея в том, что при прокрутке нижнее меню прячется, и все бы хорошо, если бы на некоторых страницах не был прикреплен к низу элемент дизайна, который оказывается виден только при спрятаным баре.

Может, есть возможность как-то изменять размер `BottomNavigationView`, что бы он всегда был виден целиком, или другой подход к этой проблеме?

Я даже думал манипулировать нижним отступом, но так и не сообразил, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал только такое решение, конечно можно оптимизировать, но работает, что мне и нужно было.

```
fun BottomNavigationView.behaviorStateListener(view: FragmentContainerView) {
        val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = layoutParams
        if (layoutParams is CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
            val behavior = layoutParams.behavior
            if (behavior is HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior) {

                behavior.addOnScrollStateChangedListener { bottomView, newState ->

                    if(newState == HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior.STATE_SCROLLED_UP){

                        val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, height)
                        animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                            val value = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int

                            view.setPadding(0,0,0, value)
                        }
                        animator.duration = 225
                        animator.start()

                    }else{

                        val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(height, 0)
                        animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                            val value = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int

                            view.setPadding(0,0,0, value)
                        }
                        animator.duration = 175
                        animator.start()

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```